# Cannot logout user on firebase when he close the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a ERP program in vue/firebase. My problem is: I need to logout the user when he closes the browser or the page who running the program.

I tried to use the setPersistence, like the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence ;
but it keeps returning an error of undefined atributes like here:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Persistence' of undefined"
(found in Root)
warn                    @   vue.esm.js?efeb:628
logError                @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1893
globalHandleError       @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1888
handleError             @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1848
invokeWithErrorHandling @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1871
callHook                @   vue.esm.js?efeb:4228
Vue._init               @   vue.esm.js?efeb:5017
Vue                     @   vue.esm.js?efeb:5094
eval                    @   main.js?3479:46
(anonymous)             @   build.js:2965
__webpack_require__     @   build.js:679
fn                      @   build.js:89
(anonymous)             @   build.js:2803
__webpack_require__     @   build.js:679
(anonymous)             @   build.js:725
(anonymous)             @   build.js:728
```

and also that:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Persistence' of undefined
    at Vue.created (main.js?3479:51)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js?efeb:1863)
    at callHook (vue.esm.js?efeb:4228)
    at Vue._init (vue.esm.js?efeb:5017)
    at new Vue (vue.esm.js?efeb:5094)
    at eval (main.js?3479:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:2965)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:679)
    at fn (build.js:89)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:2803)
```

Like i said before i'm using vue.js to develop the solution, and put it on created() function in main.js, here's my code:

```js
import FirebaseVue  from './firebase/index'
import Vue                  from 'vue'
import App                  from './App.vue'
import router           from './router'
import money                                                    from 'v-money'
import Vuelidate                                            from 'vuelidate'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin,LayoutPlugin,ModalPlugin,CardPlugin,VBScrollspyPlugin,DropdownPlugin, TablePlugin}   from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { library }                                      from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon }                      from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { VueMaskDirective }                     from 'v-mask'
import { 
    faTimesCircle,
    faPlusCircle,
    faCoffee,
    faHome,
    faLogout,
    faSignOutAlt,
    faEdit,
    faUpload,
    faDollarSign,
    faTimes,
    faClock,
    faCheck,
    faChevronLeft,
    faChevronRight,
    faArrowCircleLeft,
    faArrowCircleRight,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faTimesCircle,faPlusCircle,faCoffee,faHome,faSignOutAlt,faEdit,faUpload,faDollarSign,faTimes,faClock,faCheck,faChevronLeft,faChevronRight,faArrowCircleLeft,faArrowCircleRight)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.use(LayoutPlugin)
Vue.use(ModalPlugin)
Vue.use(CardPlugin)
Vue.use(VBScrollspyPlugin)
Vue.use(DropdownPlugin)
Vue.use(TablePlugin)
Vue.use(FirebaseVue)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
Vue.use(money, {precision: 4})
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h=>h(App),
  created(){
        
        this.$firebase.auth().setPersistence(this.$firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION),
        this.$firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
        let id_cliente = localStorage.getItem('id_cliente');
        let firebase     = this.$firebase.firestore();
            if (user) {
            
            firebase.collection('sessoes_usuarios')
            .doc(id_cliente).update({status:true})
            .then(
                console.log('usuário logado com sucesso')
            ).catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e);
                console.log('não possui log de sessão')
            });

            } else {
                
                firebase.collection('sessoes_usuarios')
                .doc(id_cliente).update({status:false})
                .then(
                    console.log('usuário deslogado com sucesso')
                ).catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e);
                console.log('não possui log de sessão')
            });

            }        
        })
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here's the firebase/index.js folder content:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey:             xxx,
  authDomain:         xxx,
  databaseURL:        xxx,
  projectId:          xxx,
  storageBucket:      xxx,
  messagingSenderId:  xxx,
  appId:              xxx      
})

export default function install (Vue) {
  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$firebase', {
    get(){
      return firebaseApp
    }
  })
}
```

Am i missing somenthing?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, i'm new on the stack. Thanks for the advice! I'm changing right now!

Comment: Can you give more info on what is `this.$firebase` and `firebase` (e.g. in `firebase.collection('sessoes_usuarios')`) and also share the content of the `/firebase/index` flie

Comment: @RenaudTarnec We use 'this.$firebase' because we have a directory with the credentials and the firebase methods imported. So when we call firebase we have to do it like a "vue function call". I'll put the firebase/index directory in an edit.
The firebase.collection('sessoes_usuarios') is a collection maded to control who is loged in or not at the moment, it's just somenthing like a "status manager" for us.

Comment: And you don't use `FirebaseVue` from `import FirebaseVue  from './firebase/index'`? Alos, is `this.$firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` triggered?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, with "this.$firebase.aut().onAuthStateChanged" is triggered normally, but a can't do the same with setPersistence() it looks like i'm missing something because it have 'undefined' return in some of my trials. So my problem is that when the user closes the webpage he keeps logged on. If there's any other way to do that i'll be very thankfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the problem is that i doens't import the auth library:

```
import 'firebase/auth'
```

I don't received any error logs before it.